# How to prevent auto-arranging of table columns upon hiding?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table of say five columns. I have the function to hide a column in jquery. But if i hide the 1st column columns 2-5 re-arrange as 1-4. How to prevent this?

Comment: How you hide? your html code?

Comment: Can u simulate the same on jsfiddle

Comment: How do you expect anyone to say what's wrong if you don't show what code you use to hide the column?

Comment: Insufficient information here to know what is really being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try with css property visibility:hidden & visible.
you can call this function onclick or onload on the table column you want.In this case space will remain same and no rearrangement will be there only data is not visible.

```
    function myFun() {
            var hideme = document.getElementById("columnId");
            hideme.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
```

In following case table will be rearranged:-

you can use slice method for it

```
 $("#tableId td").slice(<index number>, <index number>).hide();
```

OR

you can achieve this by td/th index number as :

```
 $('#tableId td:nth-child(1), #tableId th:nth-child(1)').hide();
```

Comment: This is the code i use to hide. But i actally need some help on preveting the re-arranging.

Comment: @cooltoad It's really not clear what you mean by "re-arranging". If you hide the first row, then obviously the second row is now the new first row and so on.

Comment: I agree guys but i want to make the 2nd row stay second even while hiding the 1st. Possible?

Comment: @cooltoad That just doesn't make any sense. You can't have a table that doesn't have a first row. You need to show an example of what you want. Do you mean that you want to hide the *contents* of the first row so that the first row would be blank? Or do you want to keep the *position* of other rows on the screen so that hiding the first row doesn't move them up on the page? Or do you have some sort of dynamic row numbering on the table? Or something else?

Comment: function func(id) 
        {

            $(document).ready(function () 
            {
                $(".toggle").click(function () 
                {

                    $("td:nth-child(" + id + ")").toggle();
                    
                   
                });
            });
            return false;
            }

Comment: @Juhana I want to keep the position of other rows on the screen so that hiding the first row/column  doesn't move them up on the page. the above code is what i use to hide on click.

Comment: you can do this with css property visibility:hidden.